# which applications made with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I make a windows application with Ruby?

what famous software made with Ruby (on or off the rails :D)?

everybody seems to be talking about Ruby , and I need a motivation to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly can, though it's uncommon due to Ruby's affinity to web programming.  Ruby is a cross-platform language, so if you write the code, there's a 99% chance that it will work anywhere you can install the ruby interpreter.

Specific to windows, there's the [Win32 API](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_windows.html), which allows you to interface with the windows-specific libraries from creating GUIs to getting data from the clipboard.  In addition, Ruby has modules for [WxWidgets](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl), [Qt](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/), and [GTK](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/); so a large number of cross platform GUI-toolkits are available.

As for a state of purpose, the Ruby website has a [listing of authorities](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/success-stories/) that use Ruby and what they use it for.

If you're feeling daring, you can use [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) and develop in Ruby that runs on the JVM; meaning that your program is able to run anywhere that Java can be installed.

Comment: looking at the success stories, I think that Ruby is famous for making web application not windows applications

Comment: That would be correct.  One of the major thought patterns I've seen with the ruby community was to be a replacement for Perl in enterprise applications.  Now that PHP is around, this becomes a little more of an undertone, but it's still a foundation of thought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe twitter is the most famous ruby on rails 'application' made to-date.  Making applications with ruby for windows works just like with any other scripting language. If you would like to get inspired I recommend watching some [screen casts](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/).  Also, the [starting with rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)  I found was very helpful.

Comment: I don't think Twitter has run on Rails for a long time.  I think Twitter runs on Scala now.

Comment: @AboutRuby: Twitter never went away from Rails. They didn't replace Ruby with Scala, they replaced C with Scala. Specifically, they originally envisioned Twitter as a CMS, so they naturally put a database at the center. But users used Twitter as a messaging platform, which needs a message queue at the center. So, they replaced MySQL with Starling, a message queue they had written in Ruby. However, since they never had written a message queue before, this wasn't a particularly good one, so they wrote Kestrel in Scala, which was much better, not because of Scala, but because at the second try

Comment: ... they were able to learn from their mistakes with Starling and thus actually knew what they were doing. The website has always run Rails and probably always will.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question - on the GUI side, you may want to look into the [Shoes](http://shoes.heroku.com/) toolkit. Here's a [screencast](http://remi.org/2010/01/06/gui-development-in-ruby-with-shoes) on getting started with Shoes.

You can find a list of "famous" Rails applications on the [Rails site](http://rubyonrails.org/applications).